# Installed NVIDIA-331| Unable to verify the GPU used

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus, 14.10

I've installed `nvdia-331` as suggested by `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`. **System Settings > Details** shows that I'm using `GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2` and the output of `gpu-manager`,

`last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
grep dmesg status 256
dmesg status 256 == 0? No
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is fglrx loaded? no
Was fglrx unloaded? no
Is fglrx blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is fglrx kernel module available? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:a16
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1140
BusID "PCI:4@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    eDP connector
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
Current alternative: /usr/lib/nvidia-331/ld.so.conf
Current core alternative: (null)
Is nvidia enabled? yes
Is fglrx enabled? no
Is mesa enabled? no
Is pxpress enabled? no
Is prime enabled? no
Is nvidia available? yes
Is fglrx available? no
Is fglrx-core available? no
Is mesa available? yes
Is pxpress available? no
Is prime available? yes
Intel IGP detected
Intel hybrid system
Nvidia driver version 331.113 detected
intel_matches: 1, nvidia_matches: 1, intel_set: 1, nvidia_set: 1 x_options_matches: 4, accel_method_matches: 1
No need to modify xorg.conf. Path: /etc/X11/xorg.conf
No need to change the current bbswitch status`

Shows that the NVIDIA card was detected and nouveau being blacklisted. But it also says that the ***system*** has not changed. The output of `lspci -nn` shows that the card is still a ***3D controller***. Both `nvidia-detect` and `nvidia-detector` dont detect a NVIDIA gpu.

Is the system actually using the NVIDIA gpu ?

Using 14.10 64-bit on Asus X550LD ( NVIDIA 820M ).

Comment: It also says you have Intel. So a dual video system. That either needs the newer nVidia Prime or Bumblebee to allow switching graphics. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics And often better to use newest available or even add ppa to get even newer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to dash and click on NVidia X server Settings, click on PRIME profiles and select NVIDIA(performance mode).

Shutdown and reboot your system and again check NVIDIA x server settings you will see that your system is using your NVIDIA Gpu.

Comment: Thank you ! I've also been running some CUDA programs  (Vec addition) on my system, But dont seems to run properly. What do you think I could do ?

Comment: The system is in performance mode

Comment: @kesari http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#axzz3PWkiuDx5 see the output of 'lspci | grep -i nvidia' also